# Unable to install python-apt

Tags: apt, package-management, python

This happens when I use pip:

```
user1@ubuntu-ipc:~$ pip install python-apt
Collecting python-apt
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/e5/ff/63bb64a103eda6f13364381e983c0121eeacc337a4421d6005ff7dd76741/python-apt-0.7.8.tar.bz2
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-build-OEhz4q/python-apt/setup.py", line 6, in <module>
        from DistUtilsExtra.command import *
    ImportError: No module named DistUtilsExtra.command

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-OEhz4q/python-apt/
```

This happens when I use apt:

```
user1@ubuntu-ipc:~$ sudo apt-get install python-apt
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 python-apt : Depends: libapt-inst2.0 (>= 1.6.5~) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libapt-pkg5.0 (>= 1.6.5~) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

`libapt-inst2.0` depends on `libapt-pkg5.0`, which depends on `base-files` , `base-passwd`, `bash`, `debianutils`, `diffutils`, `e2fsprogs`, `hostname`, `libapt-pkg5.0`, `libc-bin`, `ncurses-bin`, which are all installed on their newest version.

```
user1@ubuntu-ipc:~$ sudo apt-get -f install
```

results in

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Any recommendations on how to proceed?

Answer (score 0):

Install `aptitude` and try installing it with it:

```
aptitude install python-apt
```

This will give you some more options to solve the conflict